# Add ViewPagerIndicator to project

Tags: intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, android-studio, viewpagerindicator

In general such a problem trying to add ViewPagerIndicator the project.

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':SherlockTest:dexDebug'. 
> Running D:\Programs\AS\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\dx.bat failed. See output
```

depending:

**SherlockTestProject**

*settings.gradle*

```
include ':SherlockTest' 
include ':libraries:ViewPagerIndicator' 
include ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock'
```

**SherlockTest**

*build.grandle*

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' } 
    } 
    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4' 
    } 
} 
apply plugin: 'android' 

dependencies { 
    compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock') 
    compile project(':libraries:ViewPagerIndicator') 

} 

android { 
    compileSdkVersion 17 
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0" 

    defaultConfig { 
        minSdkVersion 7 
        targetSdkVersion 16 
    } 
}
```

**libraries\ActionBarSherlock**

*build.grandle*

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        mavenCentral() 
    } 
    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4' 
    } 
} 
apply plugin: 'android-library' 

dependencies { 
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') 
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar') 
} 

android { 
    compileSdkVersion 17 
    buildToolsVersion "17" 

    defaultConfig { 
        minSdkVersion 7 
        targetSdkVersion 16 
    } 


    sourceSets { 
        main { 
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml' 
            java.srcDirs = ['src'] 
            resources.srcDirs = ['src'] 
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src'] 
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src'] 
            res.srcDirs = ['res'] 
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets'] 
        } 
    } 

}
```

**libraries\ViewPagerIndicator**

*build.grandle*

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        mavenCentral() 
    } 
    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4' 
    } 
} 
apply plugin: 'android-library' 

dependencies { 
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') 
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar') 
} 

android { 
    compileSdkVersion 17 
    buildToolsVersion "17" 

    defaultConfig { 
        minSdkVersion 7 
        targetSdkVersion 16 
    } 


    sourceSets { 
        main { 
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml' 
            java.srcDirs = ['src'] 
            res.srcDirs = ['res'] 
        } 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since viewpagerindicator uses Maven, we should be able to include it like any maven project. Also, on maven, they have a tab for gradle projects. [Link to project on maven page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.viewpagerindicator/parent/2.4.1)

I am starting to write an app using this as well, so we will see how it goes.

In your build.gradle,

```
dependencies{
    ...
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:parent:2.4.1'
}
```